# cual es el uso correcto de extend?

Tags: php, poo

tengo el siguiente código:

```
namespace Pruebas\Pruebas;

class FooClass1 #aqui me hace falta algo
{

}

class FooClass2 #o es haca donde hace falta
{
    public function verificar()
    {
        echo 'hello World';
    }
}

$output = new Fooclass1();
$output->verificar();
```

el objetivo es instanciar la clase 1 y mediante  `extend` tener acceso directo a la clase 2; de tal manera que no requiera hacer la instancia de la segunda clase; teniendo en cuenta que las dos clases están en el mismo namespace y diferentes archivos.

**Update**

Intente hacer esto:

```
namespace Pruebas\Pruebas;

class FooClass1 extends FooClass2 
{

}

class FooClass2
{
    public function verificar()
    {
        echo 'hello World';
    }
}

$output = new Fooclass1();
$output->verificar();
```

y me tira este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Pruebas\Pruebas\Fooclass1::verificar() in in file...

También estoy usando el autoloader de composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Pruebas\\Pruebas\\": "src/"
    }
  }
```

las clases están ubicada en el directorio `src`

Comment: como seria con extend, limitare la pregunta entonces

Comment: dejame reviso lo que comentas pero leiste el objetivo??

Comment: es al reves; la clase 1 es una clase base que necesito que tenga acceso a los metodos en la clase 2; y que los metodos de la clase 2 puedan ser llamados desde la instancia de la clase 1.

Comment: haciendo lo que me dices me sale esto: _Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Pruebas\Pruebas\Fooclass1::verificar() in in file...._

Comment: el metodo verificaresta en la clase 2

Comment: pero ese es el resultado de tu comentario... no forma parte de la pregunta inicial...

Comment: @BetaM disculpa se me paso algo que es importante el autoloader que uso es el psr4 de composer.

Comment: Me parece que sería mejor usar una interfraz en lugar de extend.  Crear un Interface con el metodo Verificar y imiplementar ese interfraz en los dos FooClass1 y FooClass2.

Comment: entonces en la media que va creciendo la clase FooClass2 debo ir creando nuevas interfaces???

Comment: No necesariamente @FranciscoNúñez pero considera que si usas una interfaz y estableces el contrato con la misma entonces la clase donde lo hagas esta *obligada a implementar* todos los métodos de esta, por el otro lado si tienes una lógica en común para distintas entidades entonces puedes centralizarlo en un trait y de ahi reutilizarla. Por otro lado si ya estas trabajando incluso con auto carga de clases no veo por que 2 entidades deban existir en el mismo archivo, cada una debería estar por separado y si necesitas que interactúen entonces mejor por medio de su namespace por ejemplo

Comment: @BetaM puedo asegurarte que Todos los metodos existentes en la Classe 2 seran usados en la clase 1 de mi ejemplo

Comment: Si es así @FranciscoNúñez entonces considera lo que te comentó Duston

Comment: y como queda eso???

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrás que entender la *herencia de clases*, es decir

En un término que soporte cualquier lenguaje, la herencia es cuando una clase hereda los métodos y atributos de otra, para después modificarlos a su favor, es decir

Si existe una clase *bloque* y quiero un *bloque de tierra*, podemos hacer que la clase *bloque de tierra* **herede** la clase *bloque*, de manera que tenemos la clase *bloque* y la case *bloque de tierra*, la cual tiene todos los atributos y métodos de *bloque*

> Es el mecanismo en el cual una clase (Clase B), se crea a partir de otra (Clase A), adquiriendo (heredando) la clase B métodos y atributos de la clase A

[image: POO Herencia]

[Referencia en el manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Entonces, supongamos que la clase *bloque* tenga un método por defecto, el cual haga que cuando se llame, imprima *Hola mundo*, pero si quiero que la clase *bloque de tierra* imprima un mensaje diferente, usamos el **polimorfismo**

> En programación orientada a objetos, el polimorfismo se refiere a la propiedad por la que es posible enviar mensajes sintácticamente iguales a objetos de tipos distintos. El único requisito que deben cumplir los objetos que se utilizan de manera polimórfica es saber responder al mensaje que se les envía

En otros términos, el polimorfismo se refiere a modificar un método o atributo heredado a través de una clase

```
class bloque { # Definir la clase bloque
    function __construct() {
        print("Clase invocada");
    }
    public static function ejemplo() {
        print("Hello world");
    }
}

class tierra extends bloque { # Entra la herencia con extends
    # Hereda el constructor de bloque, en este caso, no lo vamos a modificar
    public static function ejemplo() {
        print("Esta es la clase Bloque de Tierra!");
    }
}

tierra::ejemplo(); # Esta es la clase Bloque de Tierra!
```

En el ejemplo anterior, la clase *bloque* tiene un constructor el cual imprimirá *Clase Invocada*, como no invocamos la clase y directamente llamamos a un método estático, no se va a ejecutar, entonces, la clase *tierra*, **hereda** a bloque, por lo cual, podemos modificar el método *ejemplo*, e imprimiremos *Esta es la clase Bloque de Tierra!*

Comment: consulta en las dos clases debe existir los metodos "ejemplo" aunque no se use jamas el de metodo bloque?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez La clase _tierra_, extiende a bloque, por lo cual, aunque no se defina _ejemplo_ en _tierra_, la clase _bloque_ también tendrá el método _ejemplo_, asimismo, si la clase _tierra_ define _ejemplo_, ese método será válido solo para esa clase

Comment: tienen que ser static??? pueden ser "public function "

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez No necesariamente tienen que ser estáticos, usé métodos estáticos como ejemplo, debido a que podemos usar `clase::metodoEstatico`

Comment: te soy sincero no me esta funcionando XD

Comment: puedes crear una sala?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119977/anythingg

Answer (score 0):

Al margen de la respuesta que ya te dieron haré los siguientes comentarios:

- Si ambas clases comparten la necesidad de todos los métodos, entonces lo mejor sería centralizarlos en algún punto y usarlos así
- Lo anterior debido a que por ejemplo si en un futuro tu clase `FooClass1` requiere heredar de alguna clase mas no podría hacerlo ya que esta heredando de `FooClass2`

Dado lo anterior, entonces deberías considerar:

- El uso de las interfaces, bajo la siguiente consideración:

Si solo requieres la declración de los métodos pero cada clase implementará estos de forma personalizada entonces ese sería el camino

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

interface operacionesAqui {
    
    public function aquiUnaAccion(): string;
    
    public function aquiOtraAccion(): string;
}

class ClaseUna implements operacionesAqui
{
    public function aquiUnaAccion(): string
    {
        return "Un valor";
    }
    public function aquiOtraAccion(): string
    {
        return "Un otro valor";
    }
}

class ClaseOtra implements operacionesAqui
{
    public function aquiUnaAccion(): string
    {
        return "Otro valor";
    }
    public function aquiOtraAccion(): string
    {
        return "Un otro valor mas";
    }
}

var_dump((new ClaseUna())->aquiUnaAccion());
var_dump((new ClaseUna())->aquiOtraAccion());

var_dump((new ClaseOtra())->aquiUnaAccion());
var_dump((new ClaseOtra())->aquiOtraAccion());
```

Dando esta salida:

```
string(8) "Un valor"
string(13) "Un otro valor"
string(10) "Otro valor"
string(17) "Un otro valor mas"
```

De modo que:

- Ambas clases tienen el *contrato* para implementar los métodos de la interfaz, pero tienen la *libertad* de que cada implementación se adapte a la necesidad planteada

Aclarando que:

- los métodos de las interfaces no deben tener cuerpo en su declaración sino hasta su implementación
- La clase estará obligada a usar todos los métodos de la interfaz

Si lo anterior no es totalmente lo aplicable, puedes pensar en los *traits* donde su puedes declarar métodos con cuerpo y así solo implementar su funcionalidad en todas las clases donde los necesites

**Lectura de interés**

- [interfaces en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.interfaces.php)
- [traits en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php)